# How do SciPy.stats distributions handle NumPy arrays in such a flexible way?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to write a class for a normal gamma distribution that can accept NumPy arrays in the same way as SciPy's pdf-functions can.
For example on the SciPy.stats multivariate_normal docs page two different usecases are shown.
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)

First

```
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 5, 10, endpoint=False)
>>> y = multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mean=2.5, cov=0.5); y
array([ 0.00108914,  0.01033349,  0.05946514,  0.20755375,  0.43939129,
        0.56418958,  0.43939129,  0.20755375,  0.05946514,  0.01033349])
>>> fig1 = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
>>> ax.plot(x, y)
```

the pdf method is applied to a 'regular' 1d-array. And a bit further down

```
>>> x, y = np.mgrid[-1:1:.01, -1:1:.01]
>>> pos = np.dstack((x, y))
>>> rv = multivariate_normal([0.5, -0.2], [[2.0, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5]])
>>> fig2 = plt.figure()
>>> ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
>>> ax2.contourf(x, y, rv.pdf(pos))
```

the pdf is applied to a 3d array of shape `(20,20,2)`.
There is a short explanation that didn't help me much:

> The input quantiles can be any shape of array, as long as the last axis labels the components.

I tried to read the source code but it surpasses my skill level.
Can someone explain (or even better show) in a simplified way how SciPy.stats handles NumPy arrays so flexibly?

Comment: Your `normal_gamma_pdf()` takes 2 arguments, `x` and `tau`. You're passing only one on `self.pdf(pos)`.

Comment: @riquefr I have used this plotting code with many 2-d functions and it worked, although I don't yet fully understand how. Other functions accepted this NumPy array as 2 Arguments without question. How do I have to change the definition that `self.pdf` does too?

Comment: You already have `X` and `T`.  Why combine them into a single array? Why not just pass them to `normal_gamma_pdf` as `self.pdf(X, T)` ?

Comment: @Basil Wouldn't I then get exactly 50 (`len(X)=50`) result values? The problem is that I need a surface plot of the 2d-input pdf and that requires the output values at every point in the 50 by 50 grid.

Comment: No, the result is a 50x50 array, just like `X` and `T` are 50x50 arrays.  Is this the result you expect? [Plot](https://i.imgur.com/9rBtRBg.png)

Comment: Yes, ty this way it works. But it does not answer the question I have in mind. I'll try to reformulate it.